# Json Patch removing sub elements in an array

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-patch

I want to remove sub elements from an array for example

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "id": "id1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "id": "id2"
        },
        {
            "name": "name3",
            "id": "id3"
        }
    ]
}
```

And i need a patch to remove all ids so i can do something like this

```
[{ "op": "remove", "path": "/employees/0/id"},
{ "op": "remove", "path": "/employees/1/id"},
{ "op": "remove", "path": "/employees/2/id"}]
```

But is there any way to specify wildcard to select all id elements in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at the [JSON patch draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-patch-10#section-1) but didn't find anything about regular expressions. One solution is to use some `JSON` parse tools to create it, like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) and [python-json-patch](https://python-json-patch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). The first one removes all `id` keys, and the second one creates a patch from a diff, used like:

```
jq 'del(.employees[].id)' jsonfile | jsondiff jsonfile -
```

It yields:

```
[{"op": "replace", "path": "/employees/2", "value": {"name": "name3"}}, 
 {"op": "replace", "path": "/employees/1", "value": {"name": "name2"}}, 
 {"op": "replace", "path": "/employees/0", "value": {"name": "name1"}}]
```

Using also the `jsonpatch` tool to apply the patch, it seems to generate a correct output, like:

```
jq 'del(.employees[].id)' jsonfile | jsondiff jsonfile - | jsonpatch jsonfile -
```

It yields:

```
{"employees": [{"name": "name1"}, {"name": "name2"}, {"name": "name3"}]}
```